# ¿Cómo repetir un bloque de código anterior en Python?

Tags: python

Partiendo del siguiente código:

```
nombre = input("Introduzca su nombre y apellido: ") 

def conmutador(): 

    
    print(f"Hola: {nombre} \nGracias por comunicarte con el 0800: SANTANDER \n")
    print("MENÚ PRINCIPAL \n1)CONOCER SALDOS Y LÍMITES \n2)OPERACIONES \n3)VOLVER AL MENÚ PRINCIPAL \n ")

    eleccion1 = int(input("INTRODUCE EL NÚMERO DE OPERACIÓN QUE DESEAS REALIZAR: "))
    if eleccion1 == 1: 
        print("\nCONOCER SALDOS Y LÍMITES \n1)CONOCER TU SALDO ACTUAL \n2)CONOCER LOS LIMITES DE TU TARJETA (DEBITO) \n")
    eleccionS = int(input("INTRODUCE EL NÚMERO DE OPERACIÓN QUE DESEAS REALIZAR: "))
    if eleccionS == 1: 
        print("Tu saldo actual es $10.000")
    elif eleccionS == 2:
        print("El limite de tu tarjeta de débito es $12.500") 
    elif eleccionS == 3: 
        print(conmutador())
    else: 
        print("No se reconoce la opción ingresada")
```

Estoy intentando crear una especie de conmutador, como cuando llamas al banco y te van dando opciones que tecleas y te redirige a nuevos menús.

La duda que tengo aquí es como hacer para ejecutar de forma correcta la línea de código: "elif eleccionS == 3:"
El objetivo de esa linae de codigo es volver al MENU principal. Concretamente, luego de ingresar el 3 deberia aparece en pantalla nuevamente el mensaje de:

```
 print("\nCONOCER SALDOS Y LÍMITES \n1)CONOCER TU SALDO ACTUAL \n2)CONOCER LOS LIMITES DE TU TARJETA (DEBITO) \n")
 eleccion1 = int(input("INTRODUCE EL NÚMERO DE OPERACIÓN QUE DESEAS REALIZAR: "))
```

y nuevamente el programa continúa en marcha.

Comment: Yo usaría un ciclo `while(flag)` alrededor de las opciones y mantendría el flag en true a menos que entre en una de las opciones 1, 2, poniéndolo false y saliendo del ciclo. Pues, es más simple.

Answer (score 0):

#### Respondiendo a tu duda

**En mi opinión** usar funciones recursivas (siempre que haya otra alternativa como un ciclo) no es una buena practica. Mi opinión se debe principalmente a que el limite de recursión es 1000. Es decir, luego de volver al menú 1000 veces ocurrirá un error.

Lo mejor que puedes hacer es envolver toda la parte del menú y el procesamiento de las opciones en un `while True` y usar `break` para romper el ciclo cuando por algún motivo deseas que una opción haga que no puedas volver al menú.

```
print(f"Hola: {nombre} \nGracias por comunicarte con el 0800: SANTANDER \n")

while True:
    print("MENÚ PRINCIPAL \n1)CONOCER SALDOS Y LÍMITES \n2)OPERACIONES \n3)VOLVER AL MENÚ PRINCIPAL \n ")

    eleccion1 = int(input("INTRODUCE EL NÚMERO DE OPERACIÓN QUE DESEAS REALIZAR: "))
    if eleccion1 == 1: 
        print("\nCONOCER SALDOS Y LÍMITES \n1)CONOCER TU SALDO ACTUAL \n2)CONOCER LOS LIMITES DE TU TARJETA (DEBITO) \n")
    eleccionS = int(input("INTRODUCE EL NÚMERO DE OPERACIÓN QUE DESEAS REALIZAR: "))
    if eleccionS == 1: 
        print("Tu saldo actual es $10.000")
        # salgo del bucle
        break
    elif eleccionS == 2:
        print("El limite de tu tarjeta de débito es $12.500")
        # salgo del bucle
        break
    elif eleccionS == 3:
        # si esta condición se cumple no hago nada
        pass
    else: 
        print("No se reconoce la opción ingresada")
```

#### Bonus: limpiar la consola

Probablemente ahora quieras que se limpie toda la consola cuando el usuario vuelve al menú. Por desgracia, Python no ofrece una forma de lograr esto. Pero puedes usar el modulo os para acceder a comandos del sistema que si pueden limpiar la pantalla.

Solo agrega `import os` al principio del código y al final del while `os.system("cls")`.